# How to fix @fontface vs. default font size - layout breaks if @fontface doesn't load

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-size

If a site is using @fontface to load 2 custom fonts and also uses ariel or sans-serif font as a default/backup font but the two fonts are very different in size - how do you fix the layout issue that occurs if the @fontface font does not load?

The issue is that the @fontface font takes up less space than the default ariel font. So if the headline is sized at 45px and the @fontface font loads perfectly within the div.  But if the @fontface font does not load in time - the default font loads instead (at 45px), and ariel is taking up more room in the div, causing the headline to break into 2 lines and thusly breaking the layout.

So how can we control BOTH the @fontface style and the default style.  Ideally, I would like to keep the h2 @fontface style at 45px and force the default font to load at 30px for the same h2 style.

Comment: great question! and wild, i was going to post the same exact question yesterday - i ended up just using Arial Narrow as a backup font since it didn't break my layout. Interested to see responses to this.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using the Google [Web Font Loader](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html) this adds additional classes to the body element which indicates if the font has: started to load, finished loading, unable to load. Using these body classes you can adjust the font styles appropriately. For example if the @font-face fails you load, you can set the font family to be smaller for the fallback font.

Comment: wow, awesome! thanks! i'll leave this open for anymore answers for a bit and award the bounty if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 5):

you can use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to generate fixed fonts.

use option `X-height Matching:` and `Adjust Glyph Spacing`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [font-size-adjust](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop) which is supported by [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS:font-size-adjust) and [Blink powered browsers](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/20c53c811469a24ea58b926f063fb53472cc62ea).

To get rid of the FOUT completely Id recommend [this method](http://www.extensis.com/en/WebINK/fout-b-gone/).

And if `@font-face` isn't supported you could use [this filter](https://github.com/Mouvedia/lack-of-font-face-support-detection) to serve javascript alternatives (like Cufón or Typeface.js).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a metric element to gauge the current actual size of the font in use, an em <=> pixel ratio.

The general idea is that you have an invisible element that uses the base font-size (like a `<span>&nbsp;</span>`) and then use javascript to measure how much (mainly height) it takes up on the rendered page.

From there, you can determine if you need to increase or decrease the active font-size to scale it to the desired design specs with javascript.

The technique of course depends on having a single base size set and everything else set in percentages (ala YUI reset/fonts style) Otherwise, you have to go through and rewrite everything and not just the style for `body`.

ref i found in my bookmarks: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fontresizing  Written during the IE7 times, but still works fine.

This technique also solves the "How do I compensate for users with zoomed text/increased font-size not breaking a page layout".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind relying on JavaScript support, you could something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) which, amongst other things, will add a `fontface` class to the `html` element if `@font-face` is supported. Then just rework your CSS to only use the better fonts if the class is present, like so:

```
h2 { font:30px/1.2 sans-serif; }
html.fontface h2 { font:45px/1.2 'awesome font', sans-serif; }
```

Comment: the disadvantage here is that often a browser *does* support @font-face, but until the font loads (or if it doesn't because of a network error, etc.) the layout is broken.

Comment: I am experimenting with font size percentages and em as well but I see the padding/margins then differ. So I can get the text itself to play nicely between the two but the spacing is far off.

Comment: @Tigger: then use different margin/padding values as well for each set of rules. You can basically make entirely different layouts depending on whether `@font-face` is supported or not with this.

Comment: So Thomas - what do you think? Is it okay to get the default font to simply meet the minimum requirement of not breaking the layout but still lack good-looking margins since the whole point is to load the page with @fontface font?  Hmm... it sounded good until I typed it out but now I realize that the person may sit on the page for quite a while - though I refresh the page when I see the issue - a typical user may not.

Comment: @Tigger personally i think if changing the font totally breaks the layout, you're doing it wrong. If a "default" font for older browsers breaks the padding/margins, consider just using text-align instead.  Even if the browser does support @font-face, the page will look ugly while the font loads *unless* you have a decent default font to resort to. That's crucial. a page that loads in chunks is NOT fun. It needs to look good as soon as it's displayed.  And you're right, the average user isn't gonna refresh the page to try to fix a broken font caused by a network error.

Comment: @marcel - great fix for the browsers that don't support @fontface like what Thomas Shields said.  But my  browsers support it and every once in a while the page loads without the fonts and my layout is messed up.  I don't think the javascript would fix the loading issue since it's unrelated to browser support.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at

http://www.options4.com/options/standards/metrics.html

you will find all of the metrics are available for you

I personally recommand `point` system if you want to use a fixed size ( `em` is too large and your numbers seems wierd )